# Reordering pages?

Tags: php, arrays

```
function update_order($id, $direction) {
  // $pages = array($pageid => $position);
  $pages = array(3 => 1, 2 => 2, 1 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5);

  // Update order
  $current = $pages[$id];
  $new = ($direction == 'up') ? ($pages[$id]++) : ($pages[$id]--);
  $old = '';

}
```

What is the quickest way to find the previous / next key from `$current` so I can add / deduct accordingly?

Comment: Could you elaborate this question?

Comment: $id++ for next and $id-- for previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use

[Previous](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php)

[Current](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)

[Next](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php)